# Mapping an open interval to a Cartesian Product question

Tags: real-analysis

I come across a question on finding a injective mappings from an open interval $(1,2]$ to a Cartesian product of $\left((-4,-3] \cup (3,4]\right) \times \{5\}$ and vice versa.

My attempt to define 2 injective mappings f and g as follows:

Define a mapping $f\colon \left((-4,-3] \cup (3,4]\right) \times \{5\} \to (1,2]$  by
$
f(x) = x+2
$.
Then define another mapping $g\colon\left((-4,-3] \cup (3,4]\right) \times \{5\} \to (1,2]$ by
$
g(y) = \frac{y+6}{2}$ for $y \in (-4,-3]$ and $g(y) = \frac{y}{2}$ for $y \in (3,4]$.

But I am troubled. Because $\left((-4,-3] \cup (3,4]\right) \times \{5\}$ should be 2-Dimensional (although it is actually 2 horizontal straight lines with $y$-coordinate $= 5$ on the Cartesian Plane). While $(1,2]$ is a 1-Dimensional.

So how can I map a 2D Cartesian Product to a 1D open interval? Are there proper way/ tricks to do the above? And please correct my definition for f and g if I am wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&(1,2]&\longrightarrow&\bigl((-4,-3]\cup[3,4)\bigr)\times\{5\}\\&x&\mapsto&\left(\frac{x+5}2,5\right)\end{array}$$is injective. And so is$$\begin{array}{rccc}g\colon&\bigl((-4,-3]\cup[3,4)\bigr)\times\{5\}&\longrightarrow&(1,2]\\&(x,5)&\mapsto&\frac{|x|}2.\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn't really think about it that way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.